# How to access to a Combo box value in Item Line on NetSuite?

Tags: combobox, netsuite

In ***NETSUITE***
is there any way to access to a value inside of a combo-box at the item line level?

I need to access to a value after inserting an item but all functions get me null value.

I have tried 
     **nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue**
and
     **nlapiGetFieldValue**

Both functions are getting me null values.

Thanks,

Pablo.

Comment: which line item field and on which record type are you trying to access? Also, can write the full code what you tried?

Comment: also, in which script are you trying - "user event/client script" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `combo box` as a mulitselect, and if you're trying to access via User Event Script, use:

```
nlapiGetLineItemValues(type, fldname, linenum);
```

Note the 's' in `nlapiGetLineItemValues`

If its just a standard field, `nlapiGetLineItemValue(type, fldname, linenum)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

In general (for user event and client script) below code should work

```
nlapiGetLineItemValue(LINE_ITEM_TYPE, YOUR_FIELD_ID, LINE_NUMBER);
```

eg on SO to get the line item Id:

```
 nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'item', 1);
```

PS: Syntax is independent of data type or field type

Answer (score 0):

Which call to use depends on what event you are capturing.

For instance if you are trying to access the value in a post sourcing, field changed or line validate event of a client script you would use nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'fieldname');